# Ungroup powerpoint objects of a jpg image

Tags: windows-7, powerpoint, office-2007

Is there a way to ungroup objects of a saved powerpoint jpg file ?
like a rectangular shape over a text made using powerpoint and saved image as jpg , is there a way to separate rectangular shape and review the text  ?

Comment: Unfortunately not - once it's in a jpg, it's "flattened" out.

Comment: @cardmagik so is it impossible to do it ?

Comment: It is impossible - whatever is covering the text can't be stripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jpg file is flat. It doesn't care if it was a face photo or a converted powerpoint; the information you want is not present in the file any more.

Comment: so is it impossible ? i.e if the text is important I can be sure that no one can review it again as far as you know ? @Amadan

Comment: @Billo: If you can't see it, it's not there. It's like if you took a photo of the screen showing your powerpoint. (Actually, if the rectangle was very very slightly transparent, you couldn't see it with your eye but could still detect it programmatically, so if you want to hide something just make sure whatever you're covering with is not transparent.)

Comment: @Billo: Not if the covering was completely opaque.

Comment: So I can be completely sure that if the rectangle was opaque no one can view the text one way or another ?

Comment: @Billo: As much as you can be sure that if you photograph a wall you can't see faces of people in the room behind it on the photo. Photos don't have layers, and neither does jpg.